Agglomerative clustering with min and max cluster size constraints
Are there any python packages that have agglomerative clustering algorithms which have min and max cluster size constraints built in?
I found a great package called KMeansConstrained but unfortunately it doesn't have agglomerative or hierarchical clustering included.
